# dotnet can't build ASP.NET Core site that's in use

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I run the command:

```
dotnet watch run
```

in my web project (ASP.NET Core) folder.
When I make changes dotnet tries to build, but get's the error:

> The process cannot access the file 'S:.......Views.dll' because it
>   is being used by another process.

I understand why I get this, the file is being used, but is there a work around this?

Comment: You get that error because the application is already running elsewhere. Check if you are running it somewhere, e.g. through Visual Studio or IIS Express. You can also check the task manager and kill the instance from there.

Comment: @poke could it be iis express? or does dotnet handle that?

Comment: If you are running the website in IIS Express, then you should stop the website there before running `dotnet run`

Comment: @poke I kinda was hoping the dotnet tool did it for me. stop on change, compile and run

Comment: If you only run the application through `dotnet run` or `dotnet watch run`, then yes, that’s what it will do. But that will require you to stop the application from running elsewhere first. So if you run it in IIS Express, shut it down there and then you can start using `dotnet watch run`.

Answer (score 0):

> The process cannot access the file […] because it is being used by another process.

When you get this error then that means that the build process cannot write to that file because the file is still in use elsewhere. In the context of a .NET application that usually means that you are *running* the application somewhere while attempting to build it.

In order to allow `dotnet run` to build the application, you will have to terminate the process that is running your application. So look for existing instances and stop them.

When launching ASP.NET Core applications through Visual Studio, the default is to run them through IIS Express. This way has the drawback that you don’t really see the process running somewhere since you do not get a console window somewhere. Instead, there is a small icon in the taskbar that shows the applications that IIS Express is hosting. You can stop the application from that icon’s menu.

If you use `dotnet watch run` *only* to run your application during development, then it will properly detect file changes to your code and restart the application. This however also means that the command line takes care of starting the application and you cannot run the application in other ways. Most importantly, you won’t be able to run and debug the application from Visual Studio with <kbd>F5</kbd>. Instead, you will have to attach to the running process of `dotnet run` to debug the application (or stop the `dotnet watch run` command).